# Shopping cart array session for empty value

Tags: php

I'm currently doing e-commerce website for fyp, selling wide range of products, and have a slight confusion about shopping cart implementation. It supposed to add to session with optional size and color (for clothes etc).

My idea:

`array('code'=>array('color'='','size'=>'','qty'=>'')`

Color and size are empty if not available. Is this a good practice to do? Can you suggest more proper way to do this?

Comment: that's a bit more general than we can answer in this forum.  We can help with errors and possible pointings to functions.

Comment: Try this tutorial https://www.withinweb.com/info/a-shopping-cart-using-php-sessions-code/

Answer (score 0):

When user will add anything to cart and its saved in Database then save other information into Database too.